# Class Instantiation returns a Function objects

Tags: scala

I am trying to understand when I create Class that extends a Trait which I believe extends Function0 [() => Unit] why does an instantiation of an object for that class is of type Function0? Is the apply method invoked as a constructor during object instantiation? I am not able to fully comprehend the mechanics of the below code.

```
scala> trait Base extends (() => Unit) {
 |
 |    def label: String
 | }
defined trait Base

scala> class Extend extends Base{
 | override def label = "Hello label"
 | override def apply()= println ("This is apply")
 |
 | }
defined class Extend

scala> val m = new Extend
m: Extend = <function0>

scala> m()
This is apply
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<function0>`-thing is not the type. That's just the output of the default `toString` method defined on `Function0`. You don't override the `toString` anywhere, so it uses the implementation from the superclass. Adding methods like `label` doesn't change anything, the compiler cannot read (your thoughts).

Little demo:

```
scala> val f = new Function0[Int]{ def apply(): Int = 42 }
f: () => Int = <function0>

scala> f.toString
res0: String = <function0>
```

On the other hand, the *type* in your example is correctly shown as `Extend`.

Comment: Thanks @Andrey, but what I am wondering is why a `new Extend` is of type of Function0 is it because `Extend extends Base extends Function0`? Also instead of `<function0>` shouldn't it be `Extend@<randomnumber>` to represent an object of the class?

Comment: @jjayadeep `new Extend` is of type `Extend`. And the repl shows exactly that: `m: Extend`. Because you've just subclassed `Function0`, `Extend` also happens to be subtype of `Function0`, I'm not sure what exactly you find surprising about it?

Comment: Okay I got it the = <function0> representation is because of the toString method. Usually when we do new Class in REPL it gives an object reference which is shown as Class@number which i believe is the toString method of AnyRef but in this case it uses toString from Function0.

Comment: @jjayadeep What it gives kind-of depends on the already provided `toString`-method... For example, the `case`-classes will usually produce much nicer human-readable output, without any hash-numbers etc. I think you've just confused the `Type` and the `ToString` parts in the `result: Type = ToString`-output of the repl, but now that seems clear.

Comment: @jjayadeep ...and the `apply` is not invoked by the constructor. It has nothing to do with the constructor at all. The `apply` is just a usual method, except that there is some syntactic sugar for it: `m()` desugars into `m.apply()`.